# How to add a view as subview for certain controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiwindow

I have multiple storyboards in my app. I want to add a view on always on the top just below the navigation bar for some of the controllers. How Can I achieve this?

I already used navigation delegate and add a view in the window but no luck. Steps to show the gray view in the attached image is.
1. On click of a button on that view controller; a gray view should show and remain on the top of the controllers until all the scanning of the device is not done whether the user should go any of the viewControllers.

[image]

Comment: Do you want that view always under a navigation bar of a navigation controller?

Comment: @ Rico Crescenzio -yes I want that view always under a navigation bar of a navigation controller but for some of the controllers

Comment: So did you try to add the view to the navigationController view instead? like `navigationController?.view.addSubview(grayView)`

Comment: It will add the the view on navigation view not below the navigation view.

Comment: Yes, you have to adjust the view position, for example add constraint to the navigation bar

Answer (score 1):

You can create a UINavigationController subclass and add the view in it.

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {

    let customView = UIView()
    let iconImgView = UIImageView()
    let msgLbl = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        customView.isHidden = true
        customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        customView.backgroundColor = .gray
        view.addSubview(customView)

        iconImgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        iconImgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        customView.addSubview(iconImgView)

        msgLbl.numberOfLines = 0
        msgLbl.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        msgLbl.textColor = .white
        msgLbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        customView.addSubview(msgLbl)

        customView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        customView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        customView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        iconImgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        iconImgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        iconImgView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        iconImgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        iconImgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: msgLbl.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true

        msgLbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        msgLbl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        msgLbl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
        msgLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    }

    func showCustomView(message: String, icon: UIImage) {
        msgLbl.text = message
        iconImgView.image = icon
        customView.isHidden = false
    }
    func hideCustomView() {
        customView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Embed all your view controllers in this navigation controller. When you want to show/hide the gray view in a view controller use

**Show**

```
(self.navigationController as? NavigationController)?.showCustomView(message: "Any Message", icon: UIImage(named: "anyImage")!)
```

**Hide**

```
(self.navigationController as? NavigationController)?.hideCustomView()
```

When you push another view controller from the same navigation controller the view won't be hidden until you call the hide method

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a custom `UIView` with the relevant `frame` and call `addSubview()` on the `view` you want to add it to.

```
lazy var customView: UIView = {
    let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: self.view.safeAreaInsets.top, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100))
    customView.backgroundColor = .gray
    return customView
}()

@IBAction func onTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.view.addSubview(customView)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.customView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

To add it below the `navigationBar`, use `y` position of `frame` as `self.view.safeAreaInsets.top`. With this your `customView` will always be aligned below the `navigationBar`.

You can create the view with the `height` as per your requirement. I've used `height = 100`.

Give the correct `frame` and you can add any view as a `subView` to another view.

[image]

Comment: @PGDev- This will add the view for all the controllers but I want to add this view for some of the controllers

Comment: Then use `self.view.addSubview(customView)` for particular controllers.

Comment: Also, kindly clarify the requirement a bit more in case it doesn't help.